# show checkbox elements of an array of checkboxes

Tags: angularjs

I have got a set of radiobuttons and an array of checkboxes. When i click radiobutton1 it should load first checkbox element from the array and when i click radiobutton2 it should load remaining 3 checkbox elements from the array.But it shows all 4 checkboxes in both the cases. I tried like this.

In HTML

```
    <form>
    <label class="radio-inline" >
    <input value="1" type="radio" ng-model="radioption" >RB1</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input value="2" type="radio" ng-model="radioption" >RB2</label>

    <div class="">
    <label ng-repeat="channel in channels | filter:myFilter" >
    <input  type="checkbox" name="selectedChannels[]"   value="{{channel.value}}"   
                ng-model="channel.selected"  >{{channel.name}}
    </label></div> 
    </form>
```

In Controller

```
App.controller('ReportController', ['$scope', 'Report',  function($scope, Report){
          var self = this;
$scope.channels = [{ name: 'A', selected: false, value: '1',visible:false },
                   { name: 'B', selected: false, value: '2' ,visible:false},
                   { name: 'C', selected: false, value: '3' ,visible:false},
                   { name: 'D', selected: false, value: '4' ,visible:false}
                  ];
    $scope.selection = [];

        $scope.selectedChannels = function selectedChannels() {
         return Report($scope.channels, { selected: true } );
        };

        $scope.$watch('channels|filter:{selected:true}', function (new) {
         $scope.selection = new.map(function (channel) {
              return channel.value;
            });
          }, true);  

        $scope.myFilter = function(){

         if ($scope.radioption == '1'){

               return $scope.channels[0].visible = true;
        }
     else if ($scope.radioption == '2'){

               return [$scope.channels[1],{ visible: true },
                       $scope.channels[2],{ visible: true },
                       $scope.channels[3],{ visible: true }];
        }
        });
 }]);
```

Comment: Why are you using filters and not directives ng-show or ng-hide?

Comment: For normal set of checkboxes i know how to use ng-show. For array i dont know how to use it. I am new to angularjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should approach this problem differently but if you want to use a filter try this

```
$scope.myFilter = function (channel) {
    if ($scope.radioption == 1) {
        if (channel.name == 'A') {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if ($scope.radioption == 2) {

        if (channel.name == 'A') {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

or you can add radioption column to channels array

```
$scope.channels = [{ name: 'A', selected: false, value: '1', radioption: 1 },
           { name: 'B', selected: false, value: '2', radioption: 2 },
           { name: 'C', selected: false, value: '3', radioption: 2 },
           { name: 'D', selected: false, value: '4', radioption: 2 }
];
```

and use ng-show

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-show="channel.radioption == radioption" name="selectedChannels[]" value="{{channel.value}}"
   ng-model="channel.selected">{{channel.name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your filter with angularJS. e.g.

```
app.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var output;
    // Do filter work here

    return output;

  }
```

Then you can use your filter in the HTML.
Also - filter should get input and return a filtered output. I think it make less sense to return a strict output regardless of the input given to it.

Take a look here, for example:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will try to change by following the example.